# how to approximate the appearance of the shadows of objects with the shadow of the background image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows, hdri

My scene is lit only with HDRi image. It has two objects and a floor made with a plane. This plane has a node material that reflects the same position as the HDRi image regardless of the camera position, simulating the same floor from HDRi. But the shadows generated in this plane are very different from the shadows of the cars in the image.[image]

Comment: I´d like to post my blender scene to became easy get help, but i didn't find where to do it.

Comment: preferably using: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com ... don't forget to pack the images.

Comment: The _image_ of the light source is a very different light-source from the original, which created the cars' shadows. In size,  distance, and also strength, even though the image is HDR. So , yes, it will be a question of how to fake a replacement light, and maybe flag out the image-lighting from that area, if necessary.

Comment: Seems like the background image was done on a bright day with no cloud coverage, the light source on  the HDr is much larger, maybe the sun is behind a cloud or maybe the HDr is not a high quality one. You need an HDR that was created in similar conditions as the original image. Then, for the placement of the shadows, you can use a texture coordinates node to rotate the HDr so that the direction of the light is similar to the background image.

Comment: so I will have to take a normal photo to use as a background image, and create an HDRi map with images of the same location and time as the background image, so that I can have the same shadow in the background image and in the shadows generated by Cycles?

Comment: Ideally the HDr and the plate should have been done at the same time , in the same place (that is how things are done in the movies), but if that is not possible, get an HDR that is done in similar circumstances.

Comment: Thank you so much guys.